# Mongoose: deep population

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have `Patient` model contains ref to `Path` :

```
const PatientSchema = Schema({
  idPatient: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  path: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Path'}
});
```

`Path` model with array of ref to `Zone`:

```
const PathSchema = connection.mongoose.Schema({
  zones: [{
    type: connection.mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Zone'
  }],
});
```

and finally `Zone` model:

```
const ZoneSchema = connection.mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  duration: Number,
});
```

I'm trying to get all the patient with their path and the zones for each path inside patient:

Here an example of data with a simple populate on the patient:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5d00b7dab927301ad392e6e4",
    "idPatient": "5d00b7dab927301ad392e6e5",
    "firstName": "Amine",
    "lastName": "Harbaoui",
    "path": {
        "_id": "5d010263b927301ad392e6ea",
        "zones": [
            "5d010c72b927301ad392e6eb",
            "5d010cf7b927301ad392e6ec"
        ]
    }
  }
]
```

And here how I tried to get what I want:

```
Patient.find()
    .lean()
    .populate('path')
    .exec((error, patients) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        const zones = patients.map(p => p.path.zones);
        Path.populate(zones, {
          path: 'zones'
        }, (error, data) => {
          if (error) {
            console.log(error);
          } else {
            console.log(data);
          }
        })
      }
    })
```

But here's the exception I get:

> { MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Zone".
>   Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
>       at new MissingSchemaError (/home/amine/ubudu/app_mn/sprint0/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/missingSchema.js:22:11)
>       at NativeConnection.Connection.model (/home/amine/ubudu/app_mn/sprint0/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:888:11)
>       at getModelsMapForPopulate (/home/amine/ubudu/app_mn/sprint0/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4337:57)
>       at populate (/home/amine/ubudu/app_mn/sprint0/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3915:21)
>       at _populate (/home/amine/ubudu/app_mn/sprint0/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3885:5)
>       at utils.promiseOrCallback.cb (/home/amine/ubudu/app_mn/sprint0/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3858:5)
>       at Object.promiseOrCallback (/home/amine/ubudu/app_mn/sprint0/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:248:12)
>       at Function.Model.populate (/home/amine/ubudu/app_mn/sprint0/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3857:16)
>       at Patient.find.lean.populate.exec (/home/amine/ubudu/app_mn/sprint0/server/controllers/patientController.js:61:14)
>       at /home/amine/ubudu/app_mn/sprint0/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4733:16
>       at /home/amine/ubudu/app_mn/sprint0/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:263:16
>       at _hooks.execPost (/home/amine/ubudu/app_mn/sprint0/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4224:11)
>       at /home/amine/ubudu/app_mn/sprint0/server/node_modules/kareem/index.js:135:16
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)   message:    'Schema hasn\'t been registered for model "Zone".\nUse
>   mongoose.model(name, schema)',   name: 'MissingSchemaError' }

Comment: The error message is saying that you haven't registered your schema for the model 'Zone'.  So the schema is either unregistered or you are referencing it incorrectly.  Make sure you have no typos and you are successfully registering it.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are using one of the more recent versions of mongoose, you can populated deeply nested values in one query.

```
Patient.find()
.populate({
    path: 'path',
    populate: {
       path: 'zones'
    }
}).exec()
```